# Audio from tts doesn't play. But tts works when used without any other code. Anything wrong here?

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
import time as tm
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()
listener = speech.Recognizer()

def bl():
        if command.lower() == "hello":
            print("Bye lol")
            tts.say("Bye lol.")
            tts.runAndWait
              
try:
    with speech.Microphone() as source:
        print('Speak Mortal')
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        print("You Said:", command)
        tm.sleep(1)
        print("Thinking")
        tm.sleep(2)
        if command.lower() == "hello":
            print("Bye lol")
            tts.say("Bye lol.")
            tts.runAndWait
        
except:
    pass
```

This works but tts doesn't play audio. But tts alone works if it's not paired with this code. I know it is my code problem as all other tests of pyttsx3 have worked. Tried replacing the whole if statement with bl():, but that didn't work either.

Comment: NVM, I'm stupid and didn't see the () after runAndWait